# Format Duration of Time

Tags: java, format, jodatime, duration

I spent all the morning trying to find out a way to achieve what I initially thought would be an relatively easy task: convert a duration of time expressed in a numeric way into a readable way. For example, for an input of 3.5, the output should be "3 years and 6 months".

According to what I was reading, it seems that Joda Time library is strongly recommended. Using that library and following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440557/joda-time-period-to-string) I was trying things like:

```
    Period p = new Period(110451600000L); // 3 years and a half

    PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
        .appendYears()
        .appendSuffix(" year", " years")
        .appendSeparator(" and ")
        .appendMonths()
        .appendSuffix(" month", " months")
        .toFormatter();

    System.out.println(formatter.print(p));
```

But the output is nothing. No idea why it's not working.

I also tried with the [Apache DurationFormatUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DurationFormatUtils.html), but doesn't work.

Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you'd be interested in this very old answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12/559299

Comment: Hinton, thanks very much for you prompt answer. Though the answer you suggested is for C#, I think I could easily adapt the algorithm. Nevertheless, it would be my last solution because I believe there should be an easier and cleaner way using Joda Time, for example. My priority is avoid reinventing the wheel :D Thanks again for your asnwer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research, tests, and the help of benjamin, I have a solution:

```
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(); // Now
    DateTime plusDuration = dt.plus(new Duration(110376000000L)); // Now plus three years and a half

    // Define and calculate the interval of time
    Interval interval = new Interval(dt.getMillis(), plusDuration.getMillis());

    // Parse the interval to period using the proper PeriodType
    Period period = interval.toPeriod(PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime());

    // Define the period formatter for pretty printing the period
    PeriodFormatter pf = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
            .appendYears().appendSuffix("y ", "y ")
            .appendMonths().appendSuffix("m", "m ").appendDays()
            .appendSuffix("d ", "d ").appendHours()
            .appendSuffix("h ", "h ").appendMinutes()
            .appendSuffix("m ", "m ").appendSeconds()
            .appendSuffix("s ", "s ").toFormatter();

    // Print the period using the previously created period formatter
    System.out.println(pf.print(period).trim());
```

I found really useful the official documentation of Joda-Time and specially this post: [Correctly defining a duration using JodaTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092883/correctly-defining-a-duration-using-jodatime)

Nevertheless, though it is working I'm not 100% happy because the output of the posted code above is "3y 6m 11h" and I don't understand the reason of those eleven hours :S Anyway, I only need precision of years and months so I believe is not a big problem. If anybody knows the reason and/or whether it could be a problem in certain scenarios, please make me know with a comment.

Answer (score 2):

The period `p` in your code does not contain years or moths, thats why the formatter does not output anything at all. Using the formatter `PeriodFormat.getDefault()`, you would see that it contains hours, namely exactly 30681 = 110451600000 / 1000 / 60 / 60.

And this is why: Milliseconds can be converted to seconds, minutes and hours in a defined way. But calculating the number of days, moths or years is ambiguous, since the number of hours of a day can be different (time zone shifting), as can the number of days in a month and number of days in a year. See the documenation: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html#Period%28long%29

As found there:

> For more control over the conversion process, you have two options:
>
> - convert the duration to an Interval, and from there obtain the period
> - specify a period type that contains precise definitions of the day and larger fields, such as UTC

Comment: Great explanation, now at least I understand the reason of my code is not working, and makes really sense. On the other hand, I don't have clear at all how to implement that in terms of doing anything that makes sense, taking into account that the time I need to convert is nothing but an amount of time or duration and nothing else. Any suggestion? Thanks a lot benjamin.

Comment: By the way, before asking I was trying with PeriodType.YearMonthDay, as the documentation says but I had the same result.

Comment: Well the actual solution to your problem depends on where your number of milliseconds come from. You could use the actual time like this: `new Duration(new DateTime(), new DateTime().plus(millis)).toPeriod();`, which could sometimes result in 3 years and 5 months, depending on when the code is executed. Or you say the milliseconds are always 'normal' days and years, then devide your milliseconds by (1000*60*60*24*365) and round to the next integer. But that's rather dirty. Specifiing a corresponding period type would be better, but I have no experience on that.

Comment: Thanks benjamin. Well, my number of milliseconds come from a decimal number which represents an amount of time in years (for example, 3.5 years). What I'm trying to do is to convert the number of years in milliseconds (3.5 years = 110376000000 ms) for a further text formatting like "3 years and 6 months". Probably I'm facing a wrong approach... what do you think?

Comment: I don't know if you have influence on that, but you could change the way of inputting years such that you receive two integers for years and moths seperately rather than a decimal. If that's not possible, do something like `int allMoths = (int) (yearsDecimal * 12); int years = months / 12; int months = allMonths % 12;`. But notice that this may result in losing precision (think of yearsDecimal = 3.14159). I definatly would prefer the first suggestion.

Comment: No, I don't have influence on that because the inputting years is a generated amount after several calculations. Honestly, the first idea I had was something similar to your last suggestion, by separating both integer and decimal parts of the number but I think is a little bit dirty and tricky hehehe This is why I tried Joda Time, thinking that it would have utils for solving my problem in a clean way. Well, I will think about a solution and I will post it when I have it working, thus it could be useful for others with the same problem. Thanks a lot bejamin for such a constructive chat!